# File permissions on HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, file-permissions

I find a lot of tutorials that guide users on how to "create users/groups" on HDFS. I wonder what an "owner" or "group" means in the context of HDFS.

Moreover, who is the owner or group user of a file when it is on HDFS? [Some](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2755708&seqNum=3) sources say it is `hdfs` itself, whereas [some](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html#The_Super-User) say it is the user of the client process.

I want to know so that there is a definitive way to understand and fix `permission denied` errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned on the first link

> A lot of the administrative HDFS commands need to be run as the “hdfs” OS user, which is the default HDFS super user

The default super user is often `hdfs`, but not necessarily.

> ... there’s no fixed super user for Hadoop. The system super user for Hadoop is simply the operating system user that starts the NameNode. The HDFS super user doesn’t have to be the root user of the NameNode host

There is no true "users/groups" in HDFS. By default, it's all a string from your local OS user. [Which is overridable by any user](https://blog.samoylenko.me/2015/05/25/hadoop-without-kerberos-examples/). Hadoop has absolutely no true authorization without Kerberos.

If you enable permisssions, then `hdfs dfs -ls` and `hdfs dfs -getfacl` shows you file permissions. `hdfs dfs -chown` and `hdfs dfs -chmod` change them.

Any HDFS user account you create should exist as an OS (or PAM or LDAP) user on the namenode at the very least for any permissions to successfully get acknowledged by HDFS clients.